# Background process takes time for execution in PHP with symfony 2.0

Tags: php, symfony, background-process

When I call to background.php for background process it takes time for execution. after execution it will execute rest of code. I want to execute it in background process. It should not wait for execution.

Below my index.php file

```
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
$_SESSION['album_upload'] = "body message";
$command = file_get_contents('background.php');
$process = new PhpProcess($command, null, array('session_id' => $session_id));
$process->run(); // Taking time for execution which should not. 
//I have also check to using `$process->start();` but it doesn't run the backround.php(I guess because I doesn't get email.).
```

below code of background.php

```
session_id($_SERVER['session_id']);
session_start();
mail("webmaster@example.com","example",$_SESSION['album_upload'],"From: $from\n");
// I also doing some copy() from another server to my server So it's take a long time.
```

I really need to execute it in background process. please give me the solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a parallel process? Should be ...

Comment: @DonCallisto Yes. I get this... $process->start() will run the code in the background without blocking. However, Symfony automatically stops child process when its main thread completes, so your email may not be sent.... How to fix it???

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all you should use the [Symfony2 mailer service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html#sending-emails) that will provide you some nice features like you need.

In fact you can [spool](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) the email message(s).

There are two methods for spooling:

- in memory: message will be sent after http page is returned to the client
- file: message will be saved to a file and you need a crontab in order to send spooled mails

I suppose that "in memory" solution will be suitable for you.

So, what you need to do?

1) Configure the spool in your `app/config/config.yml` that way

```
swiftmailer:
  spool: { type: memory }
```

2) If you're into a controller, simply request the mailer service from the container

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
```

2-1) or, if you have a service or something like, inject the mailer into and use it

3) send your email!

Comment: I am not just sending mail I am also doing copy() from another server to my server and its take so long time. and I have to do it in 30 second. I need to execute a file in Background.